# Inline-block and child div; 100% width not filling container

Tags: html, css

The site in question is located at: http://allthetime.co.nf/

This issue has been tearing me up for the last few hours. I previously wrote this menu interface with the main li elements (products, catalog, etc.) set with float:right; but for certain reasons had to rewrite it using display:inline-block and text-align:right; on the parent ul...

The problem is exemplified if you mouse over the button that says "HELP"... the menu items inside are supposed to fill the container but whatever I try there is always a large grey space to one side of them. I have tweaked every possible css property trying to make this work but to no avail. What is causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add

```
padding-left: 0px;
```

Like so

```
nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;     /* this was added */
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks. I guess I just needed to take a break and look at this from a slightly different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding on your `ul.right` in the sub menu to zero:

```
ul.right {padding: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` has left padding. Remove it and you should be okay.